# 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{ user: any; }>'

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable

I was studying an articles project and one of the services had this function:

```
 query(config: ArticleListConfig): Observable<{articles: Article[], articlesCount: number}> {

    const params = {};

    Object.keys(config.filters)
    .forEach((key) => {
      params[key] = config.filters[key];
    });

    return this.apiService
    .get(
      '/articles' + ((config.type === 'feed') ? '/feed' : ''),
      new HttpParams({ fromObject: params })
    );
  }
```

So i supposed it returned an observable object but no matter what i do it keeps not accepting the return format:

```
  query(): Observable<{user: any}>{

  return this.http.get('../../assets/data.json');
}
```

All i get is the following error:

> *Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{
>   article: any; }>'.   Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '{
>   article: any; }'.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the HttpClient what it going to get

```
return this.http.get<{user: any}>('../../assets/data.json');
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Answer (score 0):

.Have you tried something like:

Cause new HTTPCLIENT cast directly your JSON response to the type you pass to get (or post or put etc etc methid)

```
 query(): Observable<{user: any}>{

  return this.http.get<{user: any}>('../../assets/data.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a generic object in this way:

```
{[key: string]: string}
```

Or, if it will contain other values different than string:

```
{[key: string]: any}
```

If the response can be of any type, you can use `any`.